# Kaminari Change Max Per Page in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I was wondering if its possible to set the max_per_page value at the controller. I have the default set:

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.max_per_page = 100
end
```

or the `max_paginates_per` set in the model:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  max_paginates_per 100
end
```

But in the controller I want a different value... for example, use the default max for the web view, and use a different value for the API routes.  Something like:

`Test.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per]).max_per_page(500)`

Note I don't want the per to be 500... It is configurable by the parameters... I just want its max allowable value to be 500.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this cannot be done, but there is a pull request addressing the issue: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/pull/736

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

```
Test.page(params[:page]).per([params[:per].to_i, 500].min)
```

Use the supplied parameter or 500, whichever one is less.

Comment: That would work, but it will not override the default maximum set at the model or kaminari config level, so I would have to remove the default max and update all controllers to enforce the context sensitive maximum. I was hoping I could just override the maximum via a AR::Relation method.

Answer (score 0):

This is now part of kaminari. You controller call would be

Test.page(params[:page]).per(params[:per]).max_paginates_per(500)

https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/pull/754